# Bearer authority for B2Clogin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.2

in my project I have this code to manage auth (which works perfectly fine)

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
            .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
            {
                jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{b2cTenant}/{b2cPolicy}/v2.0/";
                jwtOptions.Audience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("B2CClientId");
                jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
                };
            });
```

I need to update this code to not use login.microsoftonline.com as it will soon become obsolete 
[image]

but I can't seem to find the equivalent Authority url, anyone knows? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is : $"https://{b2cTenant}.b2clogin.com/{b2cTenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{b2cPolicy}/v2.0/";

Comment: Note that it's also common to keep the `/tfp` path in the authority URL.

Comment: why? what's its purpose?

Comment: For `login.microsoftonline.com`, the `tfp` path routes requests to the Azure AD B2C STS rather than the Azure AD STS. For `{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com`, this isn't required since `.b2clogin.com` represents the Azure AD B2C STS. However, the Microsoft authentication libraries detect the `tfp` path in the authority URL and implement any Azure AD B2C logic that is necessary. This isn't necessary for an API app using the bearer authentication but it's a common convention to follow nonetheless.

Comment: This doesn't works for me. Is there anything that I am missing?